# Bad audio while sending through TCP/IP connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, naudio, tcplistener

I'm making an application that sends audio through TCP/IP connection using `NAudio`.

This is my server code:

```
        // Get server port.
        var iServerPort = GetServerPort();

        // Initialize memory stream.
        _bytes = new List<byte>();

        // Initialize tcp listener.
        var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, iServerPort);
        tcpListener.Start();

        // Accept a tcp client.
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming connection");
        _tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Client found !");

        // Buffered wave provider.
        _bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat());
        _bufferedWaveProvider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
        _bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength = iBufferBytes;

        _waveOut = new WaveOut();
        _waveOut.Init(_bufferedWaveProvider);
        _waveOut.Play();

        // Initialize a thread to listen to incoming data from another source.
        _tcpConnectionListeningThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Get data stream of tcp connection.
            var networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();

            // Initalize buffer.
            var buffer = new byte[iBufferBytes];

            // Number of bytes which have been read.

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int iReadBytes;
                    while ((iReadBytes = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        //var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        //memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, iReadBytes);
                        //_memoryStreams.Enqueue(memoryStream);
                        //_memoryStream.CopyTo();
                        //_memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, iReadBytes);
                        var realBytes = buffer.Take(iReadBytes).ToList();
                        _bytes.AddRange(realBytes);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Read: {iReadBytes} bytes. Enqueue a stream. Count: {realBytes.Count}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        // Initialize a thread to check audio buffer. Reload as audio stream consumes whole data.
        _waveBufferCheckThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Get remaining bytes in buffer.
                var iRemainingBytes = _bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes;

                // No byte is available in buffer. 
                // Check memory stream to find available bytes array. If nothing found, terminate this thread.
                if (iRemainingBytes >= iBufferBytes)
                    continue;

                // No byte available.
                if (_bytes.Count < 1)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("No data in memory stream");
                    continue;
                }

                // Get bytes array from memory stream.
                var iDifferent = iBufferBytes - iRemainingBytes;
                if (iDifferent > _bytes.Count)
                    iDifferent = _bytes.Count;

                var bytes = _bytes.GetRange(0, iDifferent).ToArray();
                _bytes.RemoveRange(0, iDifferent);

                //var bytes = new byte[iBufferBytes];
                _bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //Console.WriteLine($"Wrote {iReadBytes} to buffer. Count: {_memoryStream.Length}");
                //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                //_waveOut.Play();
            }
        });

        _tcpConnectionListeningThread.IsBackground = true;
        _waveBufferCheckThread.IsBackground = true;

        _tcpConnectionListeningThread.Start();
        _waveBufferCheckThread.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();

        _tcpConnectionListeningThread.Abort();
        _waveBufferCheckThread.Abort();
        _bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
        _waveOut.Stop();
        tcpListener.Stop();
```

This is my client code:

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize tcp client.
        _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        _recordingStream = new MemoryStream();

        _soundRecorder = new WaveIn();
        _waveOut = new WaveOut();
        _playbackBufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(_soundRecorder.WaveFormat);
        _waveOut.Init(_playbackBufferedWaveProvider);
        _soundRecorder.DataAvailable += SoundRecorderOnDataAvailable;

        btnRecord.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void SoundRecorderOnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs waveInEventArgs)
    {
        if (_networkStream != null)
        {
            _networkStream.Write(waveInEventArgs.Buffer, 0, waveInEventArgs.BytesRecorded);
            _networkStream.Flush();
        }
    }
```

My application works fine. But there is one problem I'm facing with :
- The recorded voice cannot be heard while sending to server end-point. If I save it to memory stream and play it back, the quality is ok.

Should I compress my recorded voice before sending to server ? Are there any ways to solve this issue ?

Thank you,

Comment: "recorded voice cannot be heard"? At all? Choppy? Complete silence?

Comment: You mean you cannot play it in real-time or what?

Comment: I just a static sound. I mean, sound was sent to server, but on server side, the only thing  I could hear was noise only,

Answer (score 0):

Your `_tcpConnectionListeningThread` should be writing directly into the `BufferedWaveProvider`, not going through an intermediate step of copying into an non-thread safe list. `_waveBufferCheckThread` is completely unnecessary. Update the listening thread to do something like:

```
while ((iReadBytes = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    _bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, iReadBytes);
}
```

Also you must ensure the `WaveFormat` on the server side is exactly the same as used on the client side.

Comment: I set the `_soundRecorder.DeviceNumber = -1` to stick to my current device on both server and client (tested on the same machine), but I could only heard noise. :(

Comment: to troubleshoot this kind of issue you need to divide and conquer. first record directly to WAV. Are you getting valid audio? Then receive audio from the network directly to WAV. Are you getting the same as what you sent? That way you can troubleshoot where in your pipeline of Record -> Send over network -> Playback the problem is occurring

Comment: By following NAudio example for UDP Sound streaming. I think the issue is related to sound decoder/encoder. I'll try using those encoders/decoders first and let you know my result :)